# Saving a Webpage that has intraday chart

Tags: html, google-chrome, web-scraping

Is there anyway to save a webpage with intraday chart to view it offline? (including the indicator values that we setup there.
purpose is to view the intraday charts offline. or Is there anytool that can do it.. which save all the intraday chart and can able to navigate on the chart offline. for example below site.

[image]

Comment: can you provide any link of a webpage with intraday chart?

Comment: I can, but it requires authenication, only then it will display the chart